# jQueryMobile attribute that doesn't occur any transformation

Tags: jquery, mobile, attributes, transform

Is there any attribute in jQueryMobile where I can specify that I don't to occur any transformation by jQueryMobile?

In my case it's an anchor inside data-role="header".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was wrapping the `anchor` inside a `span` or `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a link outside the jQuery Mobile "application", you can add a `rel="external"` attribute to the link's `<a>` tag to prevent jQuery Mobile from hijacking clicks on it.

Comment: It's not working, the anchor style is still being transformed by jQueryMobile.

Comment: You can see an example of that working on the jQMobile demo site: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/pages/link-formats.html I don't know if that was present in every version; are you on Alpha 3?

Comment: Yes I'm using Alpha 3. It seems rel="external" doesn't affect the page transition but the element styles are still manipulated by jQueryMobile.